# HttpClient GET request with plain querystring (together with oAuth1.0)

Tags: c#, .net, http, .net-core, get

I`m trying to do a simple request but it I can't get it to work.
I think it has something to do with the single argument.

Example code:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://www.mydomain.nl/?eq(id,8c17b598-67e4-4b9b-8d18-ab0918ed82d9)");
var consumerKey = "[mykey]";
var consumerSecret = "[mysecret]";
var token = OAuthRequest.ForRequestToken(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
token.RequestUrl = $"{uri.Scheme}://{uri.Host}{uri.AbsolutePath}";
var arguments = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);
var header = token.GetAuthorizationHeader(arguments);
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
    request.RequestUri = uri;
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", header);
    using (var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request))
    {
        var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var x = 1;
    }
}
```

I do need the authorization code for oAuth1 and it works when I try to do this without the `eq(id,8c17b598-67e4-4b9b-8d18-ab0918ed82d9)` but when adding this, it stops working. Not sure if this now is related to oAuth1 or if its related to the regular request.

But I do remember from the past that using a non-key-value query argument, that it has some issues. You guys any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that this was caused by the oAuth1 implementation I was using. I looked at a couple of examples like twitter and created my own version and compared the results with what Postman is generating and twitter showed in their example on:
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-1-0a/creating-a-signature#f2

The code that I used now:

```
/// <summary>
/// OAuth 1.0 signing
/// </summary>
public class OAuth1
{
    #region CONSTRUCTORS

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor
    /// </summary>
    public OAuth1()
    {
        this.Timestamp  = ((int)(DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds).ToString();
        this.Nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(this.Timestamp + this.Timestamp + this.Timestamp));
        this.SignatureMethod = "HMAC-SHA1";
        this.Version = "1.0";
        this.Data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    #endregion
    #region METHODS_PUBLIC

    /// <summary>
    /// Get authorization header
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string GetAuthorizationHeader()
    {
        var properties = this.GetOAuthProperties();
        properties.Add("oauth_signature", Uri.EscapeDataString(this.GetSignature()));
        return "OAuth " + string.Join(",", properties.Select(q => $"{q.Key}=\"{q.Value}\""));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get signature only
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string GetSignature()
    {
        var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(this.RequestUri);
        uriBuilder.Query = "";
        var signValues = new List<string>();
        signValues.Add(this.RequestMethod.ToString().ToUpperInvariant());
        signValues.Add(uriBuilder.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
        signValues.Add(string.Join("&", this.GetSigningProperties().Select(q => $"{q.Key}={q.Value}")));
        var signKey = $"{this.ConsumerSecret}&{this.TokenSecret}";
        var signMessage = string.Join("&", signValues.Select(q => Uri.EscapeDataString(q)));
        return this.GetSha1Hash(signKey, signMessage);
    }

    #endregion
    #region METHODS_PRIVATE

    /// <summary>
    /// Get properties which should be part of the signing process
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private SortedDictionary<string,string> GetSigningProperties()
    {
        var result = this.GetOAuthProperties();
        var arguments = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(this.RequestUri.Query);
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.Count; i++)
        {
            var key = arguments.Keys[i];
            var value = arguments.GetValues(i)[0];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
            {
                key = value;
                value = null;
            }
            result.Add(Uri.EscapeDataString(key ?? ""), Uri.EscapeDataString(value ?? ""));
        }
        foreach(var dataArg in this.Data)
        {
            result.Add(Uri.EscapeDataString(dataArg.Key), Uri.EscapeDataString(dataArg.Value));
        }
        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get SHA1 Hash
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key"></param>
    /// <param name="message"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private string GetSha1Hash(string key, string message)
    {
        var encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] keyBytes = encoding.GetBytes(key);
        byte[] messageBytes = encoding.GetBytes(message);
        string strSignature = string.Empty;
        using (var SHA1 = new HMACSHA1(keyBytes))
        {
            var Hashed = SHA1.ComputeHash(messageBytes);
            strSignature = Convert.ToBase64String(Hashed);
        }
        return strSignature;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get OAuth properties only (used for signing and header)
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private SortedDictionary<string, string> GetOAuthProperties()
    {
        var result = new SortedDictionary<string, string>();
        result.Add(Uri.EscapeDataString("oauth_consumer_key"), Uri.EscapeDataString(this.ConsumerKey));
        result.Add(Uri.EscapeDataString("oauth_nonce"), Uri.EscapeDataString(this.Nonce));
        result.Add(Uri.EscapeDataString("oauth_signature_method"), Uri.EscapeDataString(this.SignatureMethod));
        result.Add(Uri.EscapeDataString("oauth_timestamp"), Uri.EscapeDataString(this.Timestamp));
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Token))
        {
            result.Add(Uri.EscapeDataString("oauth_token"), Uri.EscapeDataString(this.Token));
        }
        result.Add(Uri.EscapeDataString("oauth_version"), Uri.EscapeDataString(this.Version));
        return result;
    }

    #endregion
    #region PROPERTIES

    /// <summary>
    /// Request method
    /// </summary>
    public Models.Thpr.Common.Enums.ERequestMethod RequestMethod { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Request URI
    /// </summary>
    public Uri RequestUri { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Timestamp
    /// </summary>
    public string Timestamp { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Nonce
    /// </summary>
    public string Nonce { get; set; } 

    /// <summary>
    /// Consumer key
    /// </summary>
    public string ConsumerKey { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Consumer secret
    /// </summary>
    public string ConsumerSecret { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Signature Method
    /// </summary>
    public string SignatureMethod { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Token
    /// </summary>
    public string Token { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Token secret
    /// </summary>
    public string TokenSecret { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Version
    /// </summary>
    public string Version { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Data arguments
    /// </summary>
    public Dictionary<string, string> Data { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```